# Fire Function when hyperlink clicked with specific class

Tags: javascript

I have a block of JS used in a TinyMCE plugin. This question is a JS query even though I'm working with TinyMCE.

This is the JS that powers the plugin:

```
tinymce.PluginManager.add("test_cat_medium_joypixels_png2", function(a, b) {
            function c() {
                var content = "<div class='custom-mce-wrapper'><div id='thing_to_stick'><a class='ignore' href='#smileyspeople'></a></div><a class='sample' href=\"#\" data-mce-url=\"https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/joypixels/assets/5.0/png/unicode/64/1f600.png\"><img src=\"https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/joypixels/assets/5.0/png/unicode/32/1f600.png\" style=\"width:32px; height:32px\"></a></div>";
                var a;
                return a = content;
            }
            a.addButton("test_cat_medium_joypixels_png2", {
                type: "panelbutton",
                text: "",
                panel: {
                    role: "application",
                    autohide: !0,
                    html: c,
                    onclick: function(b) {
                        var c = a.dom.getParent(b.target, "a");
                        c && (a.insertContent('<img src="' + c.getAttribute("data-mce-url") + '" width="64" height="64" />'), this.hide())
                    }
                },
                tooltip: "Test"
            })
        });
```

There's a block of HTML here:

```
<div class='custom-mce-wrapper'>
    <div id='thing_to_stick'><a class='ignore' href='#smileyspeople'></a></div>
    <a class='sample' href='#' data-mce-url='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/joypixels/assets/5.0/png/unicode/64/1f600.png'>
        <img src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/joypixels/assets/5.0/png/unicode/32/1f600.png' style='width:32px; height:32px'>
    </a>
</div>
```

When a link is clicked, the JS function inserts an image tag whose src is the data-mce-url attribute from the hyperlink element.

I'm struggling to work out how to change the syntax of this function:

```
onclick: function(b) {
    var c = a.dom.getParent(b.target, "a");
    c && (a.insertContent('<img src="' + c.getAttribute("data-mce-url") + '" width="64" height="64" />'), this.hide())
}
```

So that it only would fire when an hyperlink element is clicked whose class = "sample".

I don't want it to fire when a hyperlink element is clicked whose class = "ignore", or any other class, other than "sample".

I can see what I need to do, but I have no idea how to achieve it.

Sorry this is a vague question. Thanks

---

I think I worked it out:

```
a.addButton("test_cat_medium_joypixels_png2", {
    type: "panelbutton",
    text: "",
    panel: {
        role: "application",
        html: c,
        onclick: function(b) {
            var c = a.dom.getParent(b.target, "a");
            var this_class = c.getAttribute("class");
            if (this_class === "sample") {
                c && (a.insertContent('<img src="' + c.getAttribute("data-mce-url") + '" width="64" height="64" />'), this.hide())
            }
        }
    },
    tooltip: "Test"
})
```

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the exact syntax but could you change the second line of your function to `c && c.classList.contains('sample') && ...`

Comment: Thanks for your comment @IrkenInvader - I think I worked it out - answer added as edit to my question.